# How do I count how many times I've met the same element in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I have 3 different arrays and some indx variables there. I want to check how many times the same indx occurs in all three of them. I want to return the data as a list of all indx variables and the corresponding value of them according to the number of times they've occurred.


[Outline1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js77H.jpg*Outline*)


[Outline2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQZZ2.jpg)

Comment: Please review [ask] and make an [mcve] showing your attempt to solve this yourself.  At which point we can try to help you with anything you are unable to solve yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```js
var counts = {};

var arrays = {
    userX: ['indx1','indx2','indx3'],
    userY: ['indx2','indx3','indx5'],
    userZ: ['indx2','indx4','indx5']
};

for(var j in arrays){
    for(var i in arrays[j]){
        if(!counts[arrays[j][i]]){ counts[arrays[j][i]] = 0; } 
        counts[arrays[j][i]]++;
    }
}

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've imagined it to be

Answer (score 0):

I know you're getting downvoted, but I think it's a legit question and I understand what you're asking.

Use an object that maps a value to how many times you've seen it.

```
const A = [1,1,2,3];
const B = [1,3,3,3];
const arrContainer = [A, B];
const map = {};

// Loop through every array
for (const arr of arrContainer) {
  // For each value in every array, update the value in the map
  for (const val of arr) {
    if (map.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
      map[val] += 1
    } else {
      map[val] = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry if I made you guys upset, I just started learning not so long ago and I've met this problem but didn't know what article to read or how to combine what I already know to create a complex structure.

Comment: @Condomer It's okay, no worries! Stackoverflow can be a bit relentless